# Trying to create different tables for different models which are using same base abstract class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext, base-class

I have 2 models which have exactly same fields, but I chose to make different models for them because I needed two different tables, one for each.

Earlier everything was working fine when I had two different tables for each model, but then I started using abstract base class because the code inside both the models were same.

Now I have a single table comprised of all the data that I save.

How can I create different tables for those two models.

```
 public abstract class baseGrammar
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string question { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ans { get; set; }
    public string ruleId { get; set; }
    public string ruleApplicable { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ruleId")]
    public virtual ruleTable RuleTable { get; set; }
}
```

The one shown above is my abstract base class.

```
public class article : baseGrammar
{

}
 public class adjective : baseGrammar
{
}
```

Just if someone intrested in ruleTable model.

```
public class ruleTable
{
    [Key]
    public string ruleId { get; set; }
    public string topic { get; set; }
    public string rule { get; set; }
    public string example { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<baseGrammar> BaseGrammar { get; set; }
}
```

Am also adding context class so as to provide better description

```
public class english : DbContext
{
    public english() : base("name=localServerEng")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DbContext>(null);
        Database.SetInitializer<english>(new UniDBInitializer<english>());
    }

    public virtual DbSet<adjective> adjectiveDb { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<adverb> adverbDb { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<alternativeVerb> alternativeVerbDb { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<antonyms> antonymsDb { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<article> articleDb { get; set; }
private class UniDBInitializer<T> : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<english>
    {
    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<StructureSSC.Areas.AreaEnglish.Models.baseGrammar> baseGrammars { get; set; }
}
```

[Image of SQL Server showing 1 table comprising of all columns instead of different tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbd3b.png)

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt

Comment: An abstract class will never get a table. It's possible you added the `abstract` keyword later and didn't run a new migration.

Comment: No, i added abstract keyword from the very start. I just added virtual keyword before DbSet later on, however i could not figure out what difference did it make. @ChrisPratt

Answer (score 0):

Add [table data annotation](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/table-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx):

```
[Table("TABLE_NAME")]
```

Your class will look like:

```
[Table("articles")]
public class article : baseGrammar
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Table-Per-Concrete Class (TPC) Pattern using This Configurations 
 on OnModelCreating fuction

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<baseGrammar>() 
 .Property(c => c.Id) 
 .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None); 

 modelBuilder.Entity<article>().Map(m => 
 { 
 m.MapInheritedProperties(); 
 m.ToTable("article"); 
 }); 

 modelBuilder.Entity<adjective>().Map(m => 
 { 
 m.MapInheritedProperties(); 
 m.ToTable("adjective"); 
 });
```